# silverlight invisible hit area

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I would like to know how to make an invisible hit area in silverlight.  I have created a UIelement leftmousebuttondown event that calls a planeprojectionfunction(this function rotates the UIelment on its X-axis).  However as the element is rotated there is less surface area for the mouse to click on.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a canvas and set the opacity to 1%. It will increase CPU usage a little bit (usually not noticeable) but that's a quick and easy approach.

EDIT:

As KeithMahoney pointed out, don't forget to set the background to a brush with some color. Canvas by default does not have a background brush.

Comment: This will work as long as the Canvas has a Background brush set. If you set Background to "Transparent", then you don't even have to set the Opacity.